# Cannot start new activity from a surface view activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, surfaceview

So i have an activity class called MainActivity.java. Within that class i have a class called Back View that extends SurfaceView. In the BackView class is my game that is being drawn onto a canvas. When my game ends i want to be able to go back to the main menu with use of an Intent. When i do this, i see the Activity_launch_request show in the android studio run time log. The app however just freezes and goes black.

In the MainActivity class i have set up a variable called mContext.

```
Context mContext = this;
```

I have already tried the following in both MainActivity and the BackView classes:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GameMenu.class);
startActivity(Intent);
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks